# Issue with highlighting of button's border only in chrome

Tags: html, css, button

When I click on button in chrome border of button highlights, How can solve this problem? Once more question when i click on IE there is nice click effect, text inside button moves, how can I do this for all browsers ?

```
here is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qhTzT/
```

please look via ie and chrome

Comment: add `outline:0;` /*To fix the blue color outline for chrome */

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set

```
outline: 0;
```

However, the border is a usability issue set by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue with the blue border in Chrome use

```
button:focus {
    outline:none;
}
```

That the text moves in IE is a built-in function of IE, and I don't have any idea how you can solve this.